# voiceclient.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio) doesn't play any audio

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a private music bot. It joined voice channel, but no sound came out and queue didn't worked. My play function is like this:

```
async def play_music(self):
    if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
        self.is_playing = True

        index = self.music_queue[0][0]['index']

        #connecting to voice channel
        if not self.vc.is_connected():
            self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()
        else:
            await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

        self.music_queue.pop(0)

        self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(self.music_files[index], **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
```

When I execute the file, it should work like this:

```
Me: /play abc.mp3
Bot: Song added to queue.
*abc song plays in voice channel*
Me: /play def.mp3
Bot: Song added to queue.
Me: /play ghi.mp3
Bot: Song added to queue.

Me: /queue
Bot: def.mp3
     ghi.mp3
```

However, in reality, Discord:

```
Me: /play abc.mp3
Bot: Song added to queue.
*silence*
Me: /play def.mp3
Bot: Song added to queue.
Me: /play ghi.mp3
Bot: Song added to queue.

Me: /queue
Bot: No music in queue.
```

Console:

```
music found!
[[{'index': 2, 'title': 'abc.mp3'}, <VoiceChannel id=1234567890 name='VC' rtc_region=<VoiceRegion.south_korea: 'so category_id=790202432072187909>]]
music found!
[[{'index': 0, 'title': 'def.mp3'}, <VoiceChannel id=1234567890 name='VC' rtc_region=<VoiceRegion.south_korea: 's0 category_id=790202432072187909>]]

music found!
[[{'index': 1, 'title': 'ghi.mp3'}, <VoiceChannel id=1234567890 name='VC' rtc_region=<VoiceRegion.south_korea: 'south-korea'> position=5 bitrate=64000 user_limit=10 category_id=790202432072187909>]]
```

I can see something's wrong(abc and def prints shorter message in console, middle part of message is skipped), but as you can see, ***it doesn't raise any error or exception***. Could anyone please help me correct my code? I'm completely stuck, and it would be really appreciated if someone could tell me what the problem is.

Comment: Try installing PyNaCl (`pip install PyNaCl`). I had a similar issue and this worked for me.

Comment: @GabrielPery In my case, I already installed PyNaCl but it doesn't works...

Comment: Weird. Sorry I can't help further.